# c malloc for two dimensional char array by passing this array to function

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc

What is wrong with my **char ** array2;** array?

Code below is working correctly when malloc is in main function. But when malloc is in external function ...this doesn't work.

```
void function(int *var1 ,int array1[][3], char** array2);

main(){
 int var1 = 0
 int array1[10][3];
 char ** array2;

 function(&var1 , array1, array2); //Something wrong in here???

 printf("Value of var1: %d\n", var1 );                 /*Display 5 - OK*/
 printf("Value of array1[0][0]: %d\n", array1[0][0] ); /*Display 6 - OK */
 printf("Value of array2[0]: %s\n", array2[0]);        /*Error - Function stops here */
return;
}



void function(int *var1 ,int array1[][3], char** array2)
{
  int i = 0;
  array2= malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
  for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    array2[i] =  malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    strcpy(array2[i], "SomeText");
  }

  *var1 = 5;

  array1[0][0] = 6; 

  printf("Value of var1: %d\n", var1 );                 /*Display 5 - OK*/
  printf("Value of array1[0][0]: %d\n", array1[0][0] ); /*Display 6 - OK */
  printf("Value of array2[0]: %s\n", array2[0]);        /*Display "SomeText - OK*/

 return;

}
```

Comment: Asked a million times: http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [link](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html). You need to understand how are the function variables pass in C. **The variables are passed by value in C**.

Try this code:

```
void function(int *var1 ,int array1[][3], char*** array2);

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
     int var1 = 0;
     int array1[10][3];
     char **array2;

     function(&var1 , array1, &array2); //Something wrong in here???

     printf("Value of var1: %d\n", var1 );                 /*Display 5 - OK*/
     printf("Value of array1[0][0]: %d\n", array1[0][0] ); /*Display 6 - OK */
     printf("Value of array2[0]: %s\n", array2[0]);        /*Error - Function stops here */
    return;
}



void function(int *var1 ,int array1[][3], char*** array2)
{
  int i = 0;
  (*array2)= malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
  for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    (*array2)[i] =  malloc(10 * sizeof(char *));
    strcpy((*array2)[i], "SomeText");
  }

  *var1 = 5;

  array1[0][0] = 6;

  printf("Value of var1: %d\n", *var1 );                 /*Display 5 - OK*/
  printf("Value of array1[0][0]: %d\n", array1[0][0] ); /*Display 6 - OK */
  printf("Value of array2[0]: %s\n", (*array2)[0]);        /*Display "SomeText - OK*/

 return;

}
```

**Pass By Value:(in C)** from this [link](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_pass_by_value_and_pass_by_reference_in_c#ixzz21zkhnZLj).

- In this method value of the variable is passed. Changes made to formal will not affect the actual parameters.
- Different memory locations will be created for both variables.
- Here there will be temporary variable created in the function stack which does not affect the original variable.

That explains why your variable `array2` does not change in your function. The variables in C - it does not matter if it is a pointer - are always passed by value.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The link is bogus. There's no such thing as "pass by reference" in C.

Comment: @cnicutar I am not saying that C has "pass by reference". I will delete the "Pass by reference" section in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you! Great answers. But in funtion void function(int var1 ,int array1[][3], char* array2); I have int array1[][3]. And with this array I don't have use somenthing like: int *array1[][3] and then in function call function(&var1 , &array1, &array2);. The "&" for array1 is not necesary. So when I pass int array this is ..not pass by value?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
char ** array2;
```

with

```
char * array2;
```

change

```
function(&var1 , array1, array2); //Something wrong in here???
```

with

```
function(&var1 , array1, &array2);
```

and you'll be fine.

you problem was the you pass array2 (although pointer) as a value in the function.
which mean that any change you make to it won't be "seen" after the function ends.

Comment: The first change looks wrong to me.  The second change is correct, but only if the first change (suggestion is currently 'change from `char **` to `char *`') is altered.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling your function you have these :

```
(gdb) p/x &array1
$7 = 0x7fffffffe080
(gdb) p/x &array2
$8 = 0x7fffffffe108
(gdb) p/x array2
$9 = 0x0
```

So your `array1` and `array2` both resides in stack. **array2** has no value. Its not pointing to anything.

Lets call the function now,

function has its calling state like

```
function (var1=0x7fffffffe104, array1=0x7fffffffe080, array2=0x0)
```

Its expected because your `array2` is not initialized.

But inside the function look at where `array2` is located,

```
(gdb) p/x &array2
$10 = 0x7fffffffe038
(gdb) p/x &array1
$11 = 0x7fffffffe040
```

Compare this value with the earlier `&array2`. You see `array2` is located in different areas of memory in two situations. This diagram will help you to understand what happens :

```
main()'s stack : 
+---------------+
|0x7fffffffe080 |
+---------------+                  
array1
+---------------+
|0x7fffffffe108 |
+---------------+
array2

function's stack

+---------------+
|0x7fffffffe040 |
+---------------+                  
array1
+---------------+
|0x7fffffffe038 |
+---------------+ 
array2
```

So i guess you have understood that when you pass anything to a function, what it gets its a copy of the original located in its own stack.

You can't do anything with a uninitialized pointer. If you really want to change a pointer located at caller's stack, you need to pass a pointer to the original pointer.

lets say,

```
int * p; /* now it means */ 

p:
+---------------+------------+
| 0xABCD        |  0x00      |
+---------------+------------+
```

if i call a function like `foo(&p)` then in `foo`'s stack :

```
+---------------+------------+
| 0xEFGH        |  0xABCD    |
+---------------+------------+
```

Now we have a pointer to the original storage. So we can do anything with it.

Its very important to understand that like ordinary variables pointers are also follow similar rules.

You can pass a "ordinary" variable's reference with a pointer to it. But if you want to pass a reference to the pointer itself you have to go another level of indirection.

You can achieve the similar effect if you return a pointer. you can locally initialize a  pointer the return it to the caller.

Comment: Thank you! Great answers. But in funtion void function(int *var1 ,int array1[][3], char** array2); I have int array1[][3]. And with this array I don't have use somenthing like: int *array1[][3] and then in function call  function(&var1 , &array1, &array2);. The "&"
for array1 is not necesary. So when i pass int array this is reference ..not value?

Comment: the function call implementation in C does not pass a block of storage to a function whatsoever. It can't pass a array to function actually. Think about it, `int array[][3]` has arbitrary length. so you can't know how much space needs to be pushed into stack. argument registers are useless. So putting `[3]` in function prototype means nothing. You can only pass a new pointer in the called function's stack which points to array1.